How can I showcase a WordPress website I previously developed in my personal portfolio?
I am relatively new to freelancing and am currently looking for remote work opportunities that allow me to work from home. My primary skill is website development using WordPress. During my learning process, I developed two websites to showcase my abilities: one is an eCommerce website, and the other is for a real estate business. Both were created locally using XAMPP on my PC.
Recently, I managed to set up domain hosting and launched a personal portfolio website. However, I am unsure how to properly showcase the websites I developed locally on my portfolio. If anyone has a solution or advice, please share. Thank you!

This article could be a staring point for you: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-a-portfolio-to-your-wordpress-site/
